# onnx custom op registration

Tags: python, keras, onnx, onnxruntime

I am looking for a similar feature as keras custom layer in ONNX/Onnxruntime. The way I understand to solve this is to implement a custom operator in onnx for experimentation.
The documentation seems to be pointing to implementation in C++ as a shared library and use it in python.
https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/operators/add-custom-op.html

Is there a method to define custom op in python for onnx just for experimental purpose and use it for inferencing ?
I tried following this but gives 'error: PyOp is not a registered function/op'
https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/operators/custom-python-operator.html

### Python Code:

```
import onnx
import onnxruntime as ort

A = onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info('A', onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, [4])
B = onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info('B', onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, [4])
C = onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info('C', onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, [4])
D = onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info('D', onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, [4])
E = onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info('E', onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, [4])
F = onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info('F', onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, [4])

ad1_node = onnx.helper.make_node('Add', ['A', 'B'], ['S'])

mul_node = onnx.helper.make_node('Mul', ['C','D'], ['P'])

ad2_node = onnx.helper.make_node('Add', ['S', 'P'], ['H'])

py1_node = onnx.helper.make_node(op_type = 'PyOp', #required, must be 'PyOp'
                            inputs = ['H'], #required
                            outputs = ['F'], #required
                            domain = 'pyopadd_2', #required, must be unique
                            input_types = [onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT], #required
                            output_types = [onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT], #required
                            module = 'mymodule', #required
                            class_name = 'Add_2', #required
                            compute = 'compute') #optional, 'compute' by default

graph = onnx.helper.make_graph([ad1_node,mul_node,ad2_node, py1_node], 'multi_pyop_graph', [A,B,C,D], [F])
model = onnx.helper.make_model(graph, opset_imports=[onnx.helper.make_opsetid('pyopadd_2', 1)], producer_name = 'pyop_model')
onnx.save(model, './modeltemp.onnx')

ort_session = ort.InferenceSession('./modeltemp.onnx')
ort_output = ort_session.run(["F"], {'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[1,1,1,1], 'C':[2,2,2,2], 'D':[3,3,3,3]})
print(ort_output)
```

### mymodule.py

```
class Add_2:
    def compute(self, S):
        return S+2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you use the `PyOp`.
First: You need to implement the operator that you try to use in python. Second: You need to register the operator you have implemented in the ONNXRuntime session.
Third: You run the inference of the model that contains the custom ops.

One example can be found here https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions/blob/main/tutorials/tf2onnx_custom_ops_tutorial.ipynb, you have to look at the section called : "Implementing the op in python".
WARNING! `PyOp` in this notebook is called `PyCustomOpDef`
You don't need to worry about anything else in this notebook, if you start directly with the ONNX Model. Only the fact that you need to include the `"ai.onnx.contrib"` in the opset of the model and to set the same domain `"ai.onnx.contrib"` in the domain of the nodes.

```
# for the model
DOMAIN = "ai.onnx.contrib"
VERSION = 1 # try 2 or 3, I had some issues with the versioning
new_opset = onnx.helper.make_opsetid(DOMAIN, VERSION)
loaded_model.opset_import.append(new_opset)

# for the node, like in your code 
domain = 'ai.onnx.contrib', #required, must be unique
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [custom-python-operator](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/operators/custom-python-operator.html) clearly said, you must build the onnxruntime by yourself with:

`--config Release --enable_language_interop_ops --build_wheel`

The functionality does not come with the prebuilt versions of onnxruntime.